# windows phone 8 long textbox control

Tags: windows-phone-8, textbox

I am trying to figure out how to make a long text box.  I know there is an issue once the textbox is bigger than 2048.  However if you compose an email that is bigger than that it had no problem.  What type of control is used for emails?

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <TextBox />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: What's wrong with a textbox?

Comment: Once the amount of text goes over 2048 then it shows white space

Comment: Have you got code that demonstrates that issue?

Comment: I put in a really general idea of the problem.  Add that to any page and add a lot of text (copy a page of a book if you don't want to type that much) when you reach the control size limit all text afterwards becomes blank.  When I use the email app and put the same text in, it all shows so I am curious how the email app handles text input

Answer (score 0):

This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx) covers a solution for this problem. Basically you have to split text across multiple TextBlocks and then add them to a StackPanel.

```
private void ParseText(string value)
{
     if (this.stackPanel == null)
     {
         return;
     }
     // Clear previous TextBlocks
     this.stackPanel.Children.Clear();
     // Calculate max char count
     int maxTexCount = this.GetMaxTextSize();

     if (value.Length < maxTexCount)
     {
         TextBlock textBlock = this.GetTextBlock();
         textBlock.Text = value;
         this.stackPanel.Children.Add(textBlock);
     }
     else
     {
         int n = value.Length / maxTexCount;
         int start = 0;
         // Add textblocks
         for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
         {                    
             TextBlock textBlock = this.GetTextBlock();
             textBlock.Text = value.Substring(start, maxTexCount);
             this.stackPanel.Children.Add(textBlock);
             start = maxTexCount;
         }

         // Pickup the leftover text
         if (value.Length % maxTexCount > 0)
         {
             TextBlock textBlock = this.GetTextBlock();
             textBlock.Text = value.Substring(maxTexCount * n, value.Length - maxTexCount * n);
             this.stackPanel.Children.Add(textBlock);                   
         }
     }
 }
```